# Compare two Json

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to compare two elements of two different Json

Comment: the error is quite clear. `"ClusterCod"` does not apear in the json

Comment: There is ClusterCod in the json but i had to cut the json to get it inside the line limit

Comment: @AlessandoM. there's not much we can do to help you if you only provide one of the two JSON files and you cut down the one you do provide.  I can only guess that somewhere within one of your JSON files is a object that is missing a `"ClusterCod"` property.  Put a breakpoint on both lines that attempt to fetch the `"ClusterCod"`, run your code under a debugger and see which breakpoint gets hit.